# How to measure req/sec by analyzing apache logs

Tags: performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, apache-2.2

I  want to measure the justify stress-test result on production env.

How to measure req/sec by analyzing apache logs?

apache2.2

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %D" combined
```

Can I do with %t and %D parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In real time you could use [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html). You could also count the lines in your access.log over a given period and work out the rate from that. Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/var/log/apache2/access.log
STATFILE=/var/tmp/apachestats
START=$(wc -l "$LOGFILE" | awk '{print $1}')
PERIOD=10
PRECISION=2
sleep "$PERIOD"
while true
do
    HITSPERSECOND=0
    HITS=$(wc -l "$LOGFILE" | awk '{print $1}')
    NEWHITS=$(( HITS - START ))
    if [[ "$NEWHITS" > 0 ]]
    then
        START=$HITS
        HITSPERSECOND=$(echo -e "scale=$PRECISION\n$NEWHITS / $PERIOD" | bc -l )
    fi
    echo "$(date) rate was $HITSPERSECOND" >>"$STATFILE"
    sleep "$PERIOD"
done
```

Answer (score 29):

This great article helped me a lot...

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/server-usage/view-level-of-traffic-with-apache-access-log

I had created a set of prepered commands that I am using to analyze apache log:

**request per hour**
    `cat access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c`

**request per hour by date**
    `grep "23/Jan" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c`

**request per hour by IP**
    `grep "XX.XX.XX.XX" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c`

**requests per minute:**
    `cat access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c`

**requests per minute for date:**
    `grep "02/Nov/2017" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c`

**requests per minute for url:**
    `grep "[url]" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c`

**per IP per minute**
 `grep "XX.XX.XX.XX" access.log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":"$3}' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c`

hopes it will help anyone who's looking for it...

Comment: My system required quoting the bracket delimiters to make these work ( '[' and ']' ) but works fine -- example: (request per hour) cat access.log | cut -d'[' -f2 | cut -d']' -f1 | awk -F: '{print $2":00"}' | sort -n | uniq -c

Comment: @JeffClayton in my case i just had to add a space between the "d" and the "[": `cut -d [ -f2 | cut -d] -f1`

Comment: @Daviz thank you, you never know what slight differences occur between systems. I am certain someone else will find your adjustment handy as well.

Comment: Minor nit pick...  This is "requests grouped by clock hour" and similar, not exactly "requests per hour".  Requests/minute won't show 100 when 50 come in ten seconds before the minute change and 50 come in ten seconds after, it will show two separate minutes with 50 connections/minute each.  That's a subtle but important distinction to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a tool like [awstat](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

To do manually, you can count the log entries (requests) and then divide them by the number of seconds between the first and last request. So, you get the average req/sec.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run relatively short performance tests, you can keep your eye on reqs or bytes/sec in real-time with [apachetop](http://freshmeat.net/projects/apachetop/). It's like *top* command in Linux and Unix, but provides a view to your Apache. It works by tailing the access log file.

I don't know if it's accurate enough for your purposes, but it definitely gives you some nice ballpark figures.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way with gawk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
        date_hour=gensub(/^\[([^:]*:[0-2][0-9]):.*/,"\\1",1,$4)
        count[date_hour]++
}
END {
        for(i in count) {
                printf("%s %.2f%s\n",i":00",count[i]/3600,"qps")
        }
}
```